# Element with locator not found. Tried Xpath and CSS selector

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Tried using xpath locator and css on the page neither worked

I tried the following with xpath:

```
    #Wait Until Page Contains Element    //a[contains(text(), 'Service Clusters')]
```

Also tried the following:

```
    #Click Element                       //div[@id='austabsserviceTabs']/ul/li[2]/a
```

And css selector

```
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    css=a[href='#austabsserviceTabs-1']
    Click Element                       css=a[href='#austabsserviceTabs-1']
```

However I got the same error for all attempts: Element '//a[contains(text(), 'Service Clusters')]' not found.

Here is the **HTML** from the page, I'm trying to select the "Service Clusters" tab:

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">

<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
    <a href="#austabsserviceTabs-0" class="ausTabLabel">Service Profiles</a>
</li>

<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
    <a href="#austabsserviceTabs-1" class="ausTabLabel">Service Clusters</a>
</li>

<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
    <a href="#austabsserviceTabs-2" class="ausTabLabel">Service Globals</a>
</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either choose the class attribute for your Service cluster or your href attribute. It's upto you. I've tested out the xpath for your given html and I've found this `//a[@class='ausTabLabel']` Xpath to be valid for your Service Cluster. If you want to choose the href attribute then you can do something like `//a[@href='#austabsserviceTabs-1']`

The thing with Xpath is that you can choose anything you want in your html. If you need further guidance in xpath check out this website : https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html.

Answer (score 0):

try on this way may be it help you.

```
  var ul = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//ul[contains(@class,'ui-tabs-nav')]")).ToList();
  for (int i = 0; i < ul.Count; i++)
  {
      var Li = ul[i].FindElements(By.TagName("li")).ToList();
      foreach (IWebElement item in Li)
      {
            if (item.Text == "Service Clusters")
            {
               //here do whatever you want to do
               //break; if you want.
            }
      }
   }
```